# Elasticsearch how merge term frequency for two field

Tags: elasticsearch, merge, field, frequency

There is an index with a set of organizations. Each document has the name of the organization, but this name can be contained in one of two different fields. Therefore, I need to search in two fields at the same time. But here there are problems with relevance, since the frequencies of these two fields differ in the frequency of terms. Tell me how you can solve this without merging the fields into one?

Comment: Do you want to give more weight to one field than the other?

Comment: No, I need the frequency factor to be the same for the two fields

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by frequency factor  by giving an example and expected result